# Aggrid refresh after state of rowGroupPanelShow changed

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

After changing `rowGroupPanelShow` from "always" to "never" group panel top doest hide.
Is there any refreshView method i need to call from Grid instance ?

[Code](https://plnkr.co/edit/lKWdAFRfRGPB7fNM)

```
this.setState({ rowGroupPanelShow: 'never' });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to get what you want quickly is to hide that component via css. Remember to provide a unique id for your table so you can find the exact component to toggle visibility

#### Setup

```js
const showRowGroupPanel = () => {
  const el = document.querySelector(`#myTableId .ag-column-drop-wrapper`);
  el.style.display = "";
};
const hideRowGroupPanel = () => {
  const el = document.querySelector(`#myTableId .ag-column-drop-wrapper`);
  el.style.display = "none";
};

...

<button onClick={showRowGroupPanel}>Show</button>
<button onClick={hideRowGroupPanel}>Hide</button>
<div
  style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
  className="ag-theme-balham"
  id="myTableId"
>
  <AgGridReact {...}/>
</div>
```

### Live Example

[image: Edit AgGrid Toggle Row Group Panel]